# restrict number of fractional digits in datagrids cell

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid where user enter values. Here is one column:

```
<datagrid:ThemedDataGrid   AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.ItemCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                             SelectionUnit="FullRow"  
                             SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedItem}" >
                   <datagrid:ThemedDataGrid.Columns >
                       <datagrideditors:DataGridDoubleColumn  Binding="{Binding OFFSET, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="{DynamicResource Offset}" />
                   </datagrid:ThemedDataGrid.Columns>
    </datagrid:ThemedDataGrid>
```

I need to allow user to enter only 5 digids in fractional part. So I've made property OFFSET this way :

```
public new double OFFSET 
{
    get { return _offset; }
    set
    {
        int count = 0;
        bool isSeparator = false;
        char a = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
        var formatted = value.ToString().ToCharArray();
        foreach (var y in formatted)
        {
            if (!isSeparator)
            {
                if (y == a)
                {
                    isSeparator = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (isSeparator)
        {
            if (count > 5)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        _offset = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

User is not allowed to enter the sixth digit in fractional part, and here user can enter as much digits as he wants, and only when he entered value,fractional value changes to value with 5 digits in fractional part.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get English may be a second language but this is not clear

> User is not allowed to enter the sixth digit in fractional part, and
>   here user can enter as much digits as he wants, and only when he
>   entered value,fractional value changes to value with 5 digits in
>   fractional part.

Consider

```
if (count > 5) { return; }
```

You have done nothing to the value in the DataGrid
You need to assign to _offset the proper value and call OnPropertyChanged();

For example

```
if (count > 5) 
{ 
    _offset = 5.55555;
    // I leave it to you to properly assign _offset;
    OnPropertyChanged();
    return; 
}

    StringBuilder() sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var y in formatted)
    {

        if (!isSeparator)
        {
            if (y == a)
            {
                isSeparator = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            if (count > 5) break;
        }
        sb.Append(y);
    }
    if (isSeparator)
    {
        if (count > 5)
        {
            _offset = Double.Parse(sb.ToString());
            OnPropertyChanged();
            return;
        }
    }
```

And if you are on .NET 3.5 or 4.0 it then you might have a problem with the UI not updating.
But on .NET 4.5 it works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry for my english. When the sixth digit will be entered after comma, I want to delete it , so there will be always only 5 digits after comma

Comment: I answered your question.  Assign a value to _offset that only has 5 digits after the . and call OnPropertyChanged();

Comment: It's not really what I want. I want that the sixth digit will be deleted after it was entered. That's why I have if (count > 5) { return; } - so the old value with five digits  would not be changed. And in case that you proposed, I can enter 10 or 20 digits and the value will be formatted after CellEditEnding event

Comment: But your return; is not working.  I cannot be more clear than assign a value to _offset that only has 5 digits after the decimal and call OnPropertyChanged();

Comment: Sorry for my english. Let me explain in different way. I have a cell in datagrid. When there is value 1.12345 - everything is ok. When I will enter 1.123456 I want at once delete 6. With assinging value to offset and raising OnPropertyChanged event, I still see 1.123456 in cell, even in debug mode Offset is 1.12345. The Problem is that value changes in cell after CellEditEnding event, and not when I've entered sixth digit

Comment: The code I posted works.  If get or set is not getting called then you have a problem else where.  Figure it out.  Start with simple TextBox.